# How can I get corda-tools-ha-utilities-<version>.jar

Tags: corda

I can't find this corda-tools-ha-utilities-.jar from internet or enterprise version, could anyone told me that how I could get it , version 4.4 to 4.7 is ok to me . thx.

Comment: Please raise it with support.

Comment: could you pls share the guide in detail?

Answer (score 0):

For corda enterprise users you're gonna need to reach out to support as they have a specific repository for enterprise jars like the ha utilities.

The open source users can get pretty much any of the jars in their usual gradle builds. (repositories can be seen in the cordapp template here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java)